# Application that change text's size of a TextView

Tags: android, textview, size

I'm a novice programmer and I'm working on one of the my first projects on Android Studio for a school work.

I have to create an application that consists on a TextView where the user can write some text and on a button that permits to open a sort of menu where the user can choose the text's size. When the user select an option from this list, the written text should change its size.

The problem is that I don't have idea in which way I can change the size in the TextView when I select an option. Is there a specific function that permit to change the size of the written text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use those

This one is for change font in SP size:

```
TextViewXXX.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 16);
```

This one is for make text **BOLD**

```
TextViewXXX.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use `TextView.setTextSize(float)`. But, TextViews must have scale-independent pixels to [support multiple screens and font size configurations](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#terms) (sp). So, you can use `TextView.setTextSize(int unit, float size)` where the value for unit would be `COMPLEX_UNIT_SP` and size is the required size of the text.